# Как скомпилировать проект в Unity, чтобы была доступна работа с MS Sql Server

Tags: python, c#, unity3d, sql-server

Полностью реализовал игру на Unity (C# + немного Python`а). Скомпилировал проект через Build Project, но как бы не игрался с параметрами, так и не нашёл возможности локально добавить базу данных. При этом, в самом Unity Editor все функции обращения к бд были прописаны и находились в рабочем состоянии, но в скомпилированном проекте любые обращения к MS Sql Server не работают. Смешанный режим авторизации, порты TCP/IP, .dll файлы были настроены. .Net Framework использую .NET 4.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было найдено!
Что-ж, обо всём по порядку:

1. Для того, чтобы, в целом, заставить Unity работать с MS SQL Server - необходимо выполнить все шаги, описанные в моём вопросе.
2. Чтобы собрать билд проекта на Unity необходимо найти I18N.dll файлы в папке UnityHub (Зачастую сама папка подписана версией установленного Unity. Например: 2020.3.32f1)
3. Файлы которые необходимы для поиска отличаются у каждой страны. (Точно в теме не разбирался, да и на зарубежных форумах, пока ничего дельного не написали.) Скорее всего это связанно с выбором языка непосредственно в созданной локальной БД. Но лишним не будет скопировать все эти файлы.

---

В моём случае помогло сделать так:

1. Копируем все файлы I18N.dll, которые находим по пути (C:\2020.3.32f1\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\unityjit).
2. Открываем сам редактор Unity из вашего проекта для сборки.
3. Вставляем файлы в папку Assets.
4. Успешно собираем билд.
5. Вы великолепны!